# How to get xyz coordinates of pointcloud using Intel Real Sense D415?

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on Ubunto 20.4 with ROS noetic. I am having intel Real sense D415 camera by which I can visualize the point cloud on Rviz.

1. I want to get xyz coordinates of each pointcloud and from that I want to separate min and max point xyz coordinates.
2. After getting the min and max values of pointcloud i want to input my target xyz coordinates and want to compute the error difference.

I am very much new to ROS and doesn't have good programming experience as well. I will be very much thankful if anyone can share me any sample code or guide me step by step as i have searched almost all ROS forums but didn't get my answer.

I have gone through this code (https://www.programmersought.com/article/9245461951/) but it gives out several errors.

```
[ERROR] [1622062315.967796]: bad callback: <function callback_pointcloud at 0x7fe9857b61f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/arif/catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/xyz.py", line 14, in callback_pointcloud
    print (" x : %.3f  y: %.3f  z: %.3f") %(p[0],p[1],p[2])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

Kindly help me out, I will be very much thankful to you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379029/how-to-get-xyz-coordinates-of-pointcloud-using-intel-real-sense-d415?/) by [arifzaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/69915/arifzaman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on 2021-05-27**:
Concerning your error message:
The example code you referenced was written for Python2 but `noetic` uses python3 which requires brackets around the print statement. The correct syntax here , however, would be `print (" x : %.3f y: %.3f z: %.3f"  %(p[0], p[1], p[2]))` (mind the position of the brackets).
I just want to point out that that kind of sting formatting in not very common anymore in python3. See e.g. [here](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) for `str.format` or `f-strings`, which can be used more intuitively.

If you are new to ROS/ coding my general advice would be to go through some of the beginner tutorials first (if you have not done so). ROS has good tutorials for different levels of experience [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and there are tons of python tutorials out there.

You might also want to have a look at the [realsense ros wrapper examples](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/tree/development/realsense2_camera/scripts)

**Comment by [arifzaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/69915/arifzaman/) on 2021-05-29**:
Thank you so much for your comment, I have corrected my code, and now its working and giving the xyz values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks Ranjit once again, I have worked on my code and got the x,y,z coordinates and then finally got the volume of my pointcloud. But I am not sure that what is the unit of output of my x,y,z coordinates?is it in millimeters or meters?
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
from sensor_msgs import point_cloud2
from scipy.integrate import quad
import rospy
import time
import numpy as np


des_vol = input('What is the desired volume:    ')


xpoint = []
ypoint = []
zpoint = []

def callback_pointcloud(data):
    global volume
    global x
    global y
    global z
    assert isinstance(data, PointCloud2)
    gen = point_cloud2.read_points(data, field_names=("x", "y", "z"), skip_nans=True) 

    for p in gen:
      xpoint.append(p[0])
      ypoint.append(p[1])
      zpoint.append(p[2]) 
    x = max(xpoint) - min(xpoint)
    y = max(ypoint) - min(ypoint)
    cross_section = x*y
    
    def f(z):
        return cross_section
    
    i = quad(f,min(zpoint),max(zpoint))
    volume = i

def main():
    rospy.init_node('pcl_listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('/camera/depth/color/points', PointCloud2, callback_pointcloud)
    rospy.sleep(10)
    #rospy.spin()
    print ("value of x : ", x)
    print ("value of y : ", y)
    #print ("value of z : ", z)
    print ("Total initial volume is : ", volume)
    remaining_volume = volume - float(des_vol)
    quotient = remaining_volume/volume
    percentage = quotient * 100
    print("Remaining Volume needs to be completed : ",remaining_volume)
    print("Remaining Percentage needs to be completed : ",percentage)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Originally posted by [arifzaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/69915/arifzaman/) with karma: 16 on 2021-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-06-11**:\

> But I am not sure that what is the unit of output of my x,y,z coordinates?is it in millimeters or meters? Here is my code

https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html

It will me meters.

For x,y,z you will get something like this value:

x,y,z

-0.043247390386682384, 0.06332617474953332, 0.01003939218142547

**Comment by [arifzaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/69915/arifzaman/) on 2021-06-11**:
No, the values which i am getting are like:

```
value of x :  85.66250610351562
value of y :  48.047407150268555
value of z :  65.14400362968445
```

That's why I am wondering that if it is in meters then  these values i don't think right. If i am doing anything wrong?

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-06-14**:
I think you forgot to do `image_geometry.PinholeCameraModel()` and vector of that coordinate.

**Comment by [arifzaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/69915/arifzaman/) on 2021-06-17**:
Thanks Ranjit, Got your Point.